# Game does not exit when playAgain (char) is set to 'n'

Tags: c++

I have a level system in place for my Guess the Numbers game. I give the user the option to play again after guessing correctly. If only one level is active (with the other 3 being commented out) then the game will exit if the user enters `n`.

However, with all of the levels in play, the user entering `n` when prompted just prompts the user to enter their next guess.

I have achieved this using four `do while` loops with `do /*stuff*/ while (playAgain == 'y' && level == x /*1 - 4*/)`

The full code is over here [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/gJEwXqdF).

Here is a single `do while` loop, but they are the same throughout all of the loops

```
do 
{

srand(time(0)); // seed the random number generator

int theNumber = rand() % 100 + 1; // random number between 1 and 100
int tries = 0, guess;


    do
    {

        cout << "Enter a guess: ";

        string str;
        cin >> str;
        istringstream iss(str);
        iss >> guess ;
        if (iss.eof() == false)
            cout << "\n\nPlease enter only numbers.\n\n";
        else
        {

            ++tries;

            if (guess > theNumber)
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";

            if (guess < theNumber)
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
        }

    } while (guess != theNumber);

cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";

cout << "Play again? (y/n)\n";
cin >> playAgain;

} while (playAgain == 'y' && level == 1);
```

Comment: This is not a gamedev specific question. It should be asked on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your levels' do-while structures are placed sequentially.

This means that when a player chooses level 1, beats it, and decides that he/she is done, the game will automatically proceed to level 2.

Try placing:

```
cout << "Level X" << endl; // Where X is the level number
```

before the `srand(time(0));` in your levels' code and you'll see this in action.

If you want the player to view the level selection again instead, you must put that into a loop as well.

Hope this helps - good documentation by the way.

**Edit 1:**

First, what if your boss told you that this game should 100 different levels?  How would you implement that?

You could copy and paste a bunch of times, or you could rework your solution.  (Hint:  Most of the time, copying and pasting your code is a sign that you could be using loops or functions)

The only thing that changes between your levels is the range that the number is chosen from.  So, let's put those values into an array.

```
const int NUM_LEVELS = 4;
int levelRanges[NUM_LEVELS] = {100, 1000, 5000, 25000};
```

Now, instead of:

```
int theNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
```

we have:

```
int theNumber = rand() % levelRanges[level-1] + 1;
```

When `level` changes, so will the range!  Note that if the player inputs a level number that doesn't exist, bad things will happen.  To solve this, make the user pick the level again or close the game when that happens.

```
if(level < 1 || level > NUM_LEVELS){
    // Make the user repick or close the game...
}
```

Here is the new program in full:  http://pastebin.com/mNuS1sXA

Comment: I had figured this as a viable cause. As well, what do you mean by 'good documentation'? And how would one jump to the beginning again without nesting loops?

Comment: @FyrePlanet By "good documentation", I meant that you commented your code fairly well in the beginning.  As to how this problem can be solved, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @FyrePlanet I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, mate. Now I just have to study some more to understand how the implementations you used work.